# Where can I ask how to change the storage place from owncloud to a hdd?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

So I got a question about how to change the storage place from owncloud to a hdd. I am running the owncloud on Linux so I asked it at Linux, but I don't really feel like that's the right place to ask. Should I ask on Superuser? Or somewhere else? It's not really that the problem has very much to do with Linux but more the configuration of owncloud.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102045/owncloud-blank-page

Comment: Webapps, maybe? (Disclaimer: read the help center to decide if this Stacklet is right for you.)

Comment: This wouldn't be appropriate for Web Apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask in [Super User](https://superuser.com/), there is a tag for owncloud https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/owncloud

something similar to your question [Change owncloud data directory to an external drive](https://superuser.com/questions/625421/change-owncloud-data-directory-to-an-external-drive)

Comment: haha "lot of questions" 18 questions tagged with owncloud but thanks anyway

Comment: Comment to your edit: Also http://superuser.com/questions/653520/owncloud-setting-an-external-drive-as-the-default-wheezy is perfect since I am running on raspberry pi